# Where do Subiquity's (Ubuntu Server's) disk ids come from, in the disk partitioning stage?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, disk, udev, subiquity

In the manual partitioning stage of Subiquity (Ubuntu Server installer), there is a list of the disks, in the form of ids.

However, those are slightly different from the `/dev/disk/by-id` entries.

For example, Subiquity displays `VBOX_HARRDISK_VB_01234_56789`, while the corresponding `/dev/disk/by-id` file is `scsi-0ATA-VBOX_HARRDISK_VB_01234_56789`.

Where does the former come from? Is there any way to programmatically obtain it from the terminal (excluding text processing)?

Comment: I think it is read from the device ID of each disk (hardcoded). Does it match what is displayed by the following commands:  `lsblk -o name,model,serial` or `LANG=C sudo parted -ls | grep 'Model:'` and in your particular case it is the device ID of the virtual disk of VirtualBox.

Comment: @sudodus right! it was a concatenation (via underscore) of model and serial. if you convert this comment to answer, I'll accept it!

Comment: I'm glad that I could help you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the disk ID string is read from the device ID of each disk (hardcoded).

Please check if it matches what is displayed by the following commands:

```
lsblk -o name,model,serial

LANG=C sudo parted -ls | grep 'Model:'
```

In your particular case it is the device ID of the virtual disk of VirtualBox.